# Solution to "The system cannot find the file specified" – first launch of the Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, compiler-warnings

One installs Visual Studio tries any basic correct hello-world project and it won't compile.
Error message states as above.
I searched on the web and found no solution, which would make the program work in my case.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the issue in my case: **path**.

Make it as simple as possible without any non-Latin signs.
However, numbers worked fine for me and spaces may do.

*This is a truly novel solution, never found on the web, and it worked for me.*